# Set the background colour of cells via formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel:

- Cell B1: Hoe goed ken je God?
- Cell C1: HOE GOED KEN JE GOD?
- Cell D1: `=AND(B1=C1)`

The macro works and shows `TRUE` or `FALSE`

What I would now like this formula to do is set the background colour of cells `A1:E1` to **cyan** if the return value was `false`, else leave with **white** background.

Can this be done?

Comment: you will need conditional formatting.  A formula, by itself, will not change the fill color.

Comment: @ScottCraner Got it, thanks.